# TFS Build 2013 avoid code analysis

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, roslyn, fxcop

How can I avoid code analysis running on TFS Builds at a solution level?

I understand I can do this at a project level, but there are over 200 projects in my C# solution and I'd like to switch off Code Analysis at solution level if its possible.

I still need to run code analysis on developers machines.

I want to save time by not running code analysis on a specific TFS Build (we use SonarQube for CodeAnalysis on a separate build pipeline and so we don't need TFS Build to do it's own Code Analysis)

I have tried the following in my MSBuild arguments :

```
/p:RunCodeAnalysis=false
/p:RunCodeAnalysis=Never
```

*(This is using the default TfcvTemplate.12.xaml)*

But even with these changes I can still see from the build logs that Code Analysis is still occuring:

```
csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /highentropyva+ 
/debug:pdbonly /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\xyx.dll 
/ruleset:"..\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" 
/subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /utf8output 
xyz.cs
```

The full MSBuild arguments I use are:

```
/m /tv:14.0 /p:RunCodeAnalysis=false /p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=True
```

*I'm using Tools Version 14 coupled with Microsoft.Compilers NuGet package to allow C#6 on our TFS 2013 Build Server.*

Is there a way to avoid running code analysis at solution level, using just the MSBuild args in a TFS2013 build definition?

Comment: `RunCodeAnalysis=false` will turn of the old fxcop style version of code analysis. Turning off Roslyn analyzers is a bit harder: https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/issues/1711

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RunCodeAnalysis` property is used by the old style FxCop static binary analyzers. The new Roslyn Analyzers do not follow this setting.

There are two options...

You can create a `Directory.Build.targets`<sup>1</sup> file in the root folder of your solution (you can create it during build if needed) and remove the analyzers just before the compiler is invoked:

```
<Target Name="DisableAnalyzersForBuild"
        BeforeTargets="CoreCompile"
        Condition="'$(TF_BUILD)'=='True'">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Analyzer Remove="@(Analyzer)"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

You can include the `TF_BUILD` check to detect that you're inside a Team Build run.

You can also create a ruleset file that disables all rules and override that as part of the build:

```
/p:CodeAnalysisRuleSet=AllDisabled.ruleset
```

<sup>1</sup>) Not sure if this works with the Nuget compiler extensions.

Comment: Ruleset work will all analyzers so either approach mentioned here will workd